# How do I give a bootstraps id: to a dropdown menu in HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, scss-mixins

For my Ruby on Rails project I am trying to add the same id to all the parts of the header.

[Here is the effect I want on all the header elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyWOY.png)

[and here is the effect on the dropdown part of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w649.png)

Right now the I can get the links to have the id "top" as can be seen in the code below. But how can apply this id to the Account menu?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path, id: "top" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Seach", search_path, id: "top" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Courses", courses_path, id: "top" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Subjects", subjects_path, id: "top" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Instructors", instructors_path, id: "top" %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Account <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user, id: "top" %></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete, id: "top" %>
          </li>
        </ul> 
      </li>
```

You can see that I added the id: "top" to the links above and the "Profile" and "Logout" buttons in the dropdown menu, but I cannot figure out how to the "Account" part.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: try this: `Account <b class="caret"></b> <% id: "top" %>`. I hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the same html id to multiple elements on the same page. That will cause errors. Ids need to be unique to each view. To add the id to the a tag in your Account section, it can be done with

`<a href='#' class='...' id='unique-id-name'... >...</a>`

[The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_id.asp)

Comment: I added the id the way you suggested here and it seemed to work. But I did not make it unique. I am trying to add the same effect to each link/menu and that is why I kept them the same.

Comment: If you're doing something with styling or JavaScrip/jQuery, I would use classes instead. Just to avoid any complications down the road.